# Whats the role of Node.js in a Polymer setup?

Tags: node.js, npm, polymer, bower

Why do I have to install Node.js to work with Polymer? Just because of npm? Are there any other uses for Node.js in a typical Polymer project? Or is npm just used to install Bower, and Bower to install project dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is just use to create project files. create a polymer project you have to use the console polymer CLI.

once files are generated you don't need the CLI until new project or to modify the current one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Node.js. You can download all the components you want (plus all their dependencies and polyfills) from Github yourself, and organize them in your project directory. You also don't need any project files if you're going that route.

If you want, however, to conveniently install the components and all their dependencies, you can use `bower`, or the more recent `yarn`, which use Node.js. Also, if you want to host your project on Github or similar, it's useful to just commit `bower.json` which contains a list of all the dependencies (and can then conveniently be installed after cloning the repo), instead of forking all of Polymer's code into your project repo.

Having this said, if all you need is Polymer itself without any of the web components Polymer provides, it's probably even easier to just download Polymer and the required polyfills yourself.

There are more uses for Node.js. You may want to use some packages in your Polymer project, such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), which you can also just download yourself, or install using NPM/Node.

Comment: so i need node.js  just to install bower/yarn?